# sendBroadcast compile error inside run thread class method, Android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

how can I get rid of the compile error?

```
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

this method works well in another app that I made, however it has a compile error in the current app. the red underline has the eror message "undefined for the type new Runnable"

sendBroadcast() is part of the Context class, not the Intent class.

```
  public class Server {  // external class

  public class ServerThread implements Runnable {  // nested class

  public void run() {
        try {
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus = "Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP;
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (true) {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction("com.example.AudioPlay");
                            intent.putExtra("serverStatus","Connected");
                                sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }
                    });
```

<<<< EDIT >>>>

I changed the focus of the question to the compile error.  The method works fine in the other app.  It is in this particular situation where I am puzzled about the compile error.

Comment: It is giving compile error because you are not calling sendBroadcast in an Activity. This method is undefined for class Runnable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for accessing `sendBroadcast` method in a class which is not extending Activity, service or other Application components you will need to pass component context to it using class constructor as :

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {  // nested class

Context context;  //<< declare context here

public ServerThread(Context context){
  this.context=context;
}
  public void run() {

       handler.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
             public void run() {
                  Intent intent = new Intent();
                  intent.setAction("com.example.AudioPlay");
                  intent.putExtra("serverStatus","Connected");
                   // use context for calling sendBroadcast
                  context.sendBroadcast(intent);
               }
    });
```

and pass context like from Activity as :

```
ServerThread serverth=new ServerThread(Your_Current_Activity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry about the question, that was too easy. i realized my mistake a few seconds after posting.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("com.exmaple.AudioPlay");
 intent.putExtra("serverStatus","Connected");
 mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

in the other class:

```
 Server serv = new Server(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: sorry friend i think u are not getting what im saying in my comment that's why i make it as answer to make u much clear

Comment: i understand why I need to pass context for the method to work, however, you mentioned to declare Context context; in the nested class ServerThread,  how about declare it in the external class Server, would that cause any problems?